# Best way to build app for showing users GPS coordinates-React+Express?

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, express

currently I would like to build an app for showing users' GPS coordinates. GPS data will be send through the POST to server and it will be store in database. From client side there will be input for typing username, then google map will appear with current user's position. I would like to build that app using React and Express+node, is it good idea? What will be the best way to do that? How can I send GPS data from server to react and generate it on map? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The hardest thing you have to solve is getting GPS data from map, and setting map position using GPS position you have from request.

Apart from that, you just can store GPS data on some DB, using Express+Node - that seems like a suitable solution.

You will just need DB connection, and a route, that handles POST(sending GPS coordinates), and GET(getting GPS coordinates)  methods